# Semantics of assignment of an unitialized pointer in regards to structures

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, variable-assignment

Okay, let's say you have this struct:

```
struct Person
{
    int age;
    int height;
};
```

Now you have this function to create a pointer to this struct:

```
struct Person *person (int *age, int *height)
{
    struct Person *person = malloc(sizeof(Person));
    person -> age = age;
    person -> height = height;
    return person;
}
```

Then, in the main function you have this:

```
struct Person *tom;
```

Here lies my problem, I don't know if to assign these I do this:

```
*tom = person(20, 70);
```

Or this:

```
tom = person(20, 70);
```

Let me know if any further clarification is needed, I'm sure this is just a simple misunderstanding on my part, alas.

Comment: `tom = person(20, 70);` is correct. No need to dereference pointer `tom` as you are returning pointer from your function.

Comment: Also, since your `age` and `height` members are not pointers in themselves, the function signature should look like this `person (int age, int height)`.  Passing pointers there is unnecessary

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. Thank you for your (incredibly) timely response.

Comment: Note: Do not add spaces around the `->` operator. That looks plain ugly and makes it much harder to read.

Comment: Yes, that was a mistake on asking the question, in my actual program, the function signature looks as you said it should.

Comment: Gotcha. I will make the change in my program now.

Comment: Examine the types. `*tom` has type `Person` while `tom` has type `Person *`. So, if your function returns a `Person *`, then what's the *only* alternative that may possibly be correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "pointer" to an object is, for all intents and purposes, a totally separate type than the object itself.  For example, `struct Person` and `struct Person*` are two totally disparate types - you can even note this by running `sizeof(struct Person)`, and comparing that output to `sizeof(struct Person*)`.  Why is this?

Well, a "pointer" is a number.  That's all it is.  I could do [`(struct Person*) 0xDEADBEEF`](https://eval.in/411440), and it would be perfectly valid - C would accept it *(note: don't attempt to dereference it, though, because that would lead to undefined behavior)*.  However, even though a pointer is just a number, what that number *means* is more important - that number represents an address of where the actual data is stored.  But remember, all a pointer is [is just a number](https://eval.in/411443).

When you allocate some memory using `malloc`, it returns a number - this number references the point in memory that your data should be stored.  This number can be passed around just like other numbers.  However, when "dereferenced," C actually handles the data at the point in memory that you're accessing:

[image: Dereferencing a pointer]

This "number" can be returned by a function, passed to a function, and all of the other fancy things that other numbers can do.  Since the number is always unchanged, dereferencing the pointer will always point to the same place.

Your `person()` function returns a number that *happens* to address a specific place in memory that contains the Person struct.  This number is still a pointer type, so assigning it to a pointer works:

```
struct Person* person(const int age, const int height);
struct Person* newPerson;
newPerson = person(20, 40);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a pointer, so there is no need to de-reference your pointer. To make this more clear, if your function returns `struct Person *` then your variable should be `struct Person *` (there are exception to this, but this is the common rule).

This is the way to go:

```
tom = person(20, 70);
```

Also, there is no need to receive int * in your signature for (int *age, int *height):

```
struct Person *person (int *age, int *height)
```

Unless you want to modify `age` and `height` values inside the function.

I would stick with this:

```
struct Person *person (const int age, const int height)
```

Comment: @brandonb did this help?